# Dagger 2 - Tatarka DataBinding Conflict

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-apt

I try to use Dagger 2, but I've got a errors. Adding code below doesn't help me.

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "500" // or whatever number you want
  }
}
```

My build.gradle (:app) looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

...

dependencies {

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.23.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.23.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.23.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.23.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.23.2'

    compile 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter:bindingcollectionadapter:1.3.0'
}
```

I use compileSdkVersion set to 26, Gradle Wrapper set to 3.5 and
Android Gradle Build Tools set to 2.2.3.

Errors:

```
C:\Projects\xxx\app\src\main\java\pl\xxx\view\activity\MainActivity.java:31: error: package pl.xxx.databinding does not exist
import pl.xxx.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
                                        ^

C:\Projects\xxx\app\src\main\java\pl\upos\xxx\view\activity\MainActivity.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
            ^
  symbol:   class ActivityMainBinding
  location: class MainActivity
```